# Range searching for greatest cumaltive difference

Tags: arrays, ruby

So i recently took a challenge and this question really stumped me I truly don't understand what this question is requiring

> every year the census bureau takes a count of all the puppys that are born and die so if 10 are born and 5 die you are left with 5 given an arr figure out the beginning index and the ending index of the golden age of puppies

```
    example = puppy_golden_age([5, 3, -5, 1, 19, 2, -4]) = [0,5]
    example = puppy_golden_age([100, -101, 200, -3, 1000]) = [2,4]
```

this was my solution

```
def puppy_golden_age(arr)

  diff = []
  greatest = []
  0.upto(arr.length - 2) do |i|
    diff << arr[i + 1] - arr[i]
    0.upto(arr.length - 1) do |j|
      greatest << [i,j] if j >= i
    end
  end

  ranges = []
  most = 0 
  result = 0
  greatest.each_with_index do |range,i|
    range.each do |j|
      rangeSum = diff[range[0]..range[1]].inject(:+)
     (ranges << rangeSum) && (most = rangeSum) && (result = range) if most < rangeSum
    end
   end
   return result.map {|i| i + 1}
end
```

Comment: So what question are you posing to the community? Is there an error with your code? If so, what error? Are you just not getting the correct value back? If so, what is your input, current output and expected output? Are you just not sure what the challenge question is asking or how they got their results from those inputs? Right now, this is all just a statement that you don't understand it

Comment: This seems to be a [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). Other than that, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @SimpleLime im not really sure how they got to those solutions